# UserAgent in JSOUP?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have always seen everywhere in `JSOUP` code.

`Useragent` is set to Mozilla .

What if i want to set it to **google chrome or opera?**

```
Jsoup.connect(url)
      .userAgent("Mozilla");
```

How i can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

go there :

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Opera/ 
or 
http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/

and get the one you like.

for example:

```
Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6.8; U; fr) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.52");
```