# Connecting to URL and getting 401 with Java

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, http-status-code-401

I can easily get authenticated in [this site](http://br.advfn.com/p.php?pid=mon)
via browser. But there's NO POSSIBLE way to connect to it using Java. I always get 401 error. I tried to connect via Jsoup, and HTMLUnit and still nothing.. Anyone has at least some explanation as to why this is happening?

Oh, by the way... In just trying to connect to the page WITHOUT authenticating, I get the 401 error. Which in my opinion is pretty damn weird.

1. Basic `URLConnection = new URLConnection(URL);` combo (Native Java API) didn't work.
2. Jsoup with `Document = Response.parse();` didn't work
3. HTMLUnit using `WebClient` didn't work either
4. Any of the above trying to emulate a browser didn't work as well

Answer (score 1):

The 401 error is an authentication error. This is *likely* because the agent you are specifying (or failing to specify) when you connect isn't considered valid. (There could be more than that, depending on how that site is set up.)

You can specify a user agent in JSoup, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10187724/597849) to that question on SO.

Comment: Nop. Tried it with 3 different browsers, and still nothing

Answer (score 1):

If you use `HttpURLConnection`, maybe it helps...

```
java.net.Authenticator.setDefault( new Authenticator() {
  protected java.net.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new java.net.PasswordAuthentication ("user", "pass".toCharArray());
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem itself is not authenticating. In OPENING the page, I get the 401 error. I tried getting cookies from the main page, and then redirecting to the login page, and I still get the 401 error. That's the part I think it's weird..

Comment: OK. I used that, and still got nowhere. Thank you anyway.