# Java Web Scraping using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to make a java application which can scrape infos off web sites, and I've done some googling, and managed very simple scraper, but not enough.
It seems that my scraper is not scraping some information on this website, espesially the part where I want to scrape. [image]

1.

```
        Elements links = htmlDocument.select("a");
        for (Element link : links) {
           this.links.add(link.attr("href"));
        }
```

2. 

```
        Elements linksOnPage = htmlDocument.select("a[href]");
        System.out.println("Found (" + linksOnPage.size() + ") links");
        for(Element link : linksOnPage)
        {
            this.links.add(link.absUrl("href"));
        }
```

I've tried both code, but I cant find that link anywhere in Elements object.
I believe that those information I want is the result of search, so when my program connects to that url, that information are gone. How can I solve this? I want an program whenever it gets started, scraping the result of that search.

Here is the [link to the web site](http://www.work.go.kr/empInfo/empInfoSrch/list/dtlEmpSrchList.do?pageIndex=2&pageUnit=50&len=0&tot=0&relYn=N&totalEmpCount=0&jobsCount=0&mainSubYn=N&region=41000&lastIndex=1&siteClcd=all&academicGbnoEdu=noEdu&firstIndex=1&pageSize=10&recordCountPerPage=10&preferentialGbn=all&rowNo=0&softMatchingPossibleYn=Y&benefitSrchAndOr=O&staAreaLineInfo1=11000&staAreaLineInfo2=1&keyword=CAD&charSet=EUC-KR&startPos=0&collectionName=tb_workinfo&softMatchingMinRate=%2066&softMatchingMaxRate=100&enterPriseGbn=all&termSearchGbn=all&empTpGbcd=1&onlyTitleSrchYn=N&onlyContentSrchYn=N&serialversionuid=3990642507954558837&cloTermSearchGbn=all&resultCnt=50&sortOrderBy=DESC&sortField=DATE)

So my question is,

1.How do I scrape that link into my code's Elements object? What am I doing Wrong?

2.Is there any way to pick that link and proceed to that link only(not all hyperlinks)?

```
    final Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.work.go.kr/empInfo/empInfoSrch/list/dtlEmpSrchList.do?pageIndex=2&pageUnit=10&len=0&tot=0&relYn=N&totalEmpCount=0&jobsCount=0&mainSubYn=N&region=41000&lastIndex=1&siteClcd=all&firstIndex=1&pageSize=10&recordCountPerPage=10&rowNo=0&softMatchingPossibleYn=N&benefitSrchAndOr=O&keyword=CAD&charSet=EUC-KR&startPos=0&collectionName=tb_workinfo&softMatchingMinRate=+66&softMatchingMaxRate=100&empTpGbcd=1&onlyTitleSrchYn=N&onlyContentSrchYn=N&serialversionuid=3990642507954558837&resultCnt=10&sortOrderBy=DESC&sortField=DATE").userAgent(USER_AGENT).get();


    try
    {
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(USER_AGENT);
        Document htmlDocument = connection.get();
        this.htmlDocument = htmlDocument;
        String qqq=htmlDocument.toString();
        System.out.println(qqq);
        if(connection.response().statusCode() == 200) // 200 is the HTTP OK status code
                                                      // indicating that everything is great.
        {
            System.out.println("\n**Visiting** Received web page at " + url);
        }
        if(!connection.response().contentType().contains("text/html"))
        {
            System.out.println("**Failure** Retrieved something other than HTML");
            return false;
        }
        
        Elements linksOnPage = htmlDocument.select("a[href]");
        System.out.println("Found (" + linksOnPage.size() + ") links");
        for(Element link : linksOnPage)
        {
            this.links.add(link.absUrl("href"));
            System.out.println(link.absUrl("href"));
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        // We were not successful in our HTTP request
        return false;
    }
```

this is the entire code I use for scraping.
This code, I'm using [from this site.](http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-simple-web-crawler-in-java/)

Comment: Maybe this link is generated with Javascript ? Try this http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsoup/4632/parsing-javascript-generated-pages#t=201702071004321608713

Comment: I found out that in my code, when I try to connect to the webpage showing results of some search, the webpage responds with empty results,while on the browser(chrome)shows the right result.(even if I use the same url) . I printed out text of Document, and at the part where should be the result of search, the webpage says "cannot find the page you requested". So.. can anybody help this?

Comment: Have you tried to set the User Agent when connecting to the URL ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187603/useragent-in-jsoup

Comment: Post more of your code - how do you fetch the HTML?

Comment: I edited my question with my code. How do I check if right user agent for my browser..?And if useragent were wrong, shouldn't I get no response at all? I'm confused.. or Is it possible that the website I'm trying to scrap is blocking me for security purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, and couldn't resolve it. So, what I was trying was that I wanted to scrape info from a webpage showing some results of specific search. The issue was that the website is somehow not letting me to connect from my java application using jsoup. Probably to protect their contents. That's why there's was no elements I needed, because it's actually not there. The website offers openAPI for charge, so I decided to use other websites.